# How can I add priority fee to

Tags: solana-cli

how to add a priority fee `metaplex.nfts().printNewEdition(editionParams, { commitment: "confirmed" })` how do I set fee for printing edition from master edition.

Comment: Please post your full code for us to be able to help you better.